# What happens to the Thanos gauntlet after use?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Why does Thanos's gauntlet look destroyed after he used it at the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 23):

As Eitri defines the gauntlet as 'a device capable of harnessing the power of the stones', it actually stands up to that, but please note that the Infinity Stones are depicted as the most powerful entities there are in the MCU.

It shall be no surprise seeing the gauntlet decay after using up its full potential, viz not only keeping all stones together, but using them ALL at a particular instance.

Also, it's not right to comment until seeing *Avengers: Endgame* whether the gauntlet can be used again or not.

Comment: Agreed. EndGame should give some answers to this question.

Comment: Thanos used the gauntlet to teleport away, and possibly to heal himself, after the snap.

Comment: Yes, he used the Soul stone to talk to dead gamora etc, but I meant that there is a question of using the Gauntlet as a whole, all 6 stones together !

Comment: @masterArSuKa Since Avengers: Endgame has already been released, feel free to update the question to explain what happened to the gauntlet, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 19):

Director **[Joe Russo](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0751648/)** says in the **[audio commentary for the movie](https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-snap-permanently-damaged-thanos-gauntlet/)**:

> *See there, with his Gauntlet and the arm, **the power that it takes to
>   use all six Stones is significant, and clearly damaged the Gauntlet**
>   and damaged Thanos permanently.*

Answer (score 5):

The Gauntlet acted as a conduit for the Infinity Stones. The scope of the Decimation exceeded the conductive capacity of the Gauntlet and burned it out. This would be similar to how a conductor would burn up if too much current was passed through it.